# How can I save user input as a variable in javascript with a button onclick?

Tags: javascript, variables, input, onclick

I want to save what the user types in the input as a variable when the user clicks the button.  Than, I want to console.log the new variable with the users information.  What am I doing wrong?

```html
<html>    
    <div class="container bg-light">
        <div class="row">
    
          <div class="col-md-3 bg-danger">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group text-center">
              <h1>Saving User Data as a Variable with Javascript</h1>
    
              <div class="form-group">
                <input id="userdata" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mx-auto text-center">
    
                <button type="button" onclick="saveUserData()" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg mx-auto w-50 text-center">Check console</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 bg-danger">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <script>
      function saveUserData() 
      {
     // store the tag with id="sign" in var userdata
     var userdata = document.getElementById("userdata");
      }
      
      // confirm the element exists and what value the user submits
     console.log(userdata);
     console.log("users value is: " + userdata.value);
      </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You define `userdata` inside function `saveUserData()` but you try to show the value out of the function where `userdata` is not defined. Your script is also immediatly executed so you see an empty value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function saveUserData() {
   var name = document.getElementById('userdata').value;
   
   console.log("users value is: " + name);
}
```

```html
<div class="container bg-light">
        <div class="row">
    
          <div class="col-md-3 bg-danger">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group text-center">
              <h1>Saving User Data as a Variable with Javascript</h1>
    
              <div class="form-group">
                <input id="userdata" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mx-auto text-center">
    
                <button type="button" onclick="saveUserData()" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg mx-auto w-50 text-center">Check console</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 bg-danger">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function saveUserData() {
 var userdata = document.getElementById('userdata').value;
 console.log("users value is: " + userdata);
}
```

Comment: didn't work I got this error... Uncaught ReferenceError: saveUserData is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: This code was ok. you can't defined saveUserData function at HTMLButtonElement.

Comment: @TonyCarbetta Edit your question to your latest code. And this answer needs some explanations.